# $F$ is in the neighorhood of $L$ , $\lim_{z\to L} F(z) = F(L),$ and $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = L.$ Show $\lim_{x\to x_0}F(f(x))=F(L)$

Tags: real-analysis

How do I prove this using $\delta$ and $\epsilon$?

Would the $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ be defined with regard to the limit of $f$ or the limit of $F$?

Or do each of them need their own $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ defined separately?

Comment: There is a typo in the title. What is $\lim_{x\to x_0} =$?

Comment: @ArcticChar There is no typo. That's the limit as $x$ approaches some $x_o$

Comment: @Adam: I guess what you wrote is likely what the OP is asking, but you should really tell them clarify.

Comment: I am concerned with $=$. $\lim_{x\to x_0} g(x) = ??$ makes sense, while $\lim_{x\to x_0}=$ does not.

Comment: Since your question had been edited, please check if that is what you want.

Comment: @ArcticChar, the edit is fine. How I had it originally is how the text had presented it. But this works as well.

Comment: I am not allowed to provide an actual answer until you show work.  You need a third variable (e.g. $\alpha$).  Given $\epsilon > 0$ you should be able to find $\delta$ so that when $x$ is in a neighborhood of radius $\delta$ around $L$, $F(x)$ will be in a neighborhood of radius
$\epsilon$ around $F(L)$.  Further, given
$\delta$, you should be able to find an $\alpha$ so that when $x$ is in a neigborhood of
radius $\alpha$ around $x_0$, then $f(x)$ is in a neighborhood of radius $\delta$ around $L$ which implies
that $F[f(x)]$ is in a neighborhood of radius $\epsilon$ around $F(L).$

Comment: @Arctic Char "I guess what you wrote is likely what the OP is asking, but you should really tell them clarify". OP can choose to reject my proposed changes though, so it's effectively the same thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\lim_{z\to L} F(z) = F(L)$ means $$\forall \epsilon_1>0\exists\delta_1>0: d(z,L)<\delta_1\implies d(F(z),F(L))<\epsilon_1$$
and $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = L$ means $$\forall \epsilon_2>0\exists\delta_2>0: d(x,x_0)<\delta_2\implies d(f(x),L)<\epsilon_2.$$
You want to show $\lim_{x\to x_0} F(f(x)) = F(L)$, which means  $$\forall \epsilon>0\exists\delta>0: d(x,x_0)<\delta\implies d(F(f(x)),F(L))<\epsilon.$$
Take any $\epsilon>0$. Now you have to show that such a $\delta>0$ exists.

Choose $\epsilon_1=\epsilon$, so you find a $\delta_1>0$ according the first equation with $d(F(z),F(L))<\epsilon$ for all $z$ with $d(z,L)<\delta_1$. Now choose $\epsilon_2=\delta_1$, so you find a $\delta_2>0$ according the second equation with $d(f(x),L)<\epsilon_2=\delta_1$ for all $x$ with $d(x,x_0)<\delta_2$. Alltogether you found a $\delta_2>0$ with $d(F(f(x)),F(L))<\epsilon$ for all $d(x,x_0)<\delta_2$.